# How to conditionally render a prop in TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, tsx

I am trying to do the following in a functional component using TypeScript (I abstracted it a bit):

```
return <IonToast {canClose && button={close}}
```

It isn't allowed to wrap a prop inside a conditional. But what would be the best solution to have such logic?

I though about assigning the 'close' variable before the return, but since Ionic is an external component library, it doesn't accept an empty variable.

The IonToast is typed in node-modules with the following. So it doesn't like it if you pass anything but a valid value.

```
export interface ToastOptions {
    buttons?: (ToastButton | string)[];
}
```

The ts error goes like this

```
Types of property 'button' are incompatible.     Type 'string | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.       Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

Comment: `button={canClose && close}`?

Comment: I think we should pass an empty function instead. `button={canClose ? close : () =>{}}` that would help to prevent errors from unexpected `close()` calls inside that component

Comment: Yes, but since its an external library, it's typed in the node modules and it doesn't allow for 'undefined', looking for a workaround on this.

Comment: How about the following? `return canClose ? <IonToast buttons={close}/> : <IonToast />`

Comment: @qrsngky yes that would work indeed! But I have about 10~ other props, and it would feel a bit bad to have all that duplicate code

Comment: Hmm this comment section is not good enough for an explanation. I put it under the answer section with the update instead @SaroVerhees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

According to [this document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast)

You can have this logic for your `buttons` attribute

```
const buttons: ToastButton[] = canClose ? [close] : [] //`close` needs to be `ToastButton` type
return <IonToast buttons={buttons} />
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I don't know which is the best solution for this case, but I'm personally using this way

```
return <IonToast button={canClose ? close : () =>{}} />
```

The second param is an empty function that would help to prevent errors, just in case you call `button()` (indirect to `close()`) in `IonToast` component.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solution to accomplish this. If you have many properties under the same condition you can wrap them in an object. Since `IonToast` expect props of a shape -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast#toastoptions you should use `buttons` instead of `button`

```
return <IonToast {...(canClose && {buttons:[close]})}
```

Comment: `{button={close}}` this is not a valid object

Comment: Oh right, let me fix that, error of copy paste, @BrianThompson thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Now its valid but still wrong. button should be a function not another object - `button: close`

Comment: what component library are you using?

Comment: @lissettdm Ionic 6, its about the IonToast component -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast

Comment: According to API, component is expected other props  -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast#toastoptions

Comment: close is a button?